# Prevent users from selecting multiple cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to let users select the cell they want to edit.

```
Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Click the cell you want to edit.", Title:="Cell To Edit", Type:=8)
```

How can I change my code so they can only select one cell at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Range

    Do
        On Error Resume Next
        Set r = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Click the single cell you want to edit.", _
                                     Title:="Cell To Edit", _
                                     Type:=8)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        If r.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            MsgBox "Please select a single cell only"
            Set r = Nothing
        End If
    Loop

    'MsgBox r.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: That is very close to what I had. I just needed to count the cells and loop until the user clicked a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("A1:A2")
    While r.Count <> 1
        Set r = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Click the cell you want to edit.", Title:="Cell To Edit", Type:=8)
    Wend
End Sub
```